# Show that preimage is an embedded surface

Tags: manifolds

I have given a function
$$f:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3: (x,y,z,u) \mapsto (xz-y^2, yu-z^2,xu-yz)$$
and I want to show that $f^{-1}(0)\setminus\{0\}$ is an embedded surface.
If it would be an embedded curve I could verify that $f$ is an submersion to get a 1-dim submanifold. But I don't know how to show that this is an embedded surface.

Comment: 1st get $f$'s the derivative

Comment: Are you sure this is right? It seems to consist of the $x$-axis, the $u$-axis, and the curve $(t^2,t,1,1/t)$. Moreover, $f$ has rank $3$ along the non-linear curve. I was expecting all the components of $f$ to be homogeneous.

Comment: sorry there was a mistake on the last component.

Comment: The derivative is given by:
$$Df(x,y,z,u) = \begin{pmatrix} z & -2y & x & 0\\ 0 & u & -2z & y\\ u & -z & -y & x\end{pmatrix}$$
which has rank 3 for all $(x,y,z,u) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \setminus \{0\}$
So, $f^{-1}(0)\setminus\{0\}$ is not an embedded surface but an 1-dim submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
Is this argumentation right?

Comment: @AndreasK... but at $(x,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,u)$ has rank two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this problem from Amann's Analysis II, page 257.

Note that
$$\begin{aligned}
y^2&=xz\\
z^2&=yu\\
yz&=xu.
\end{aligned}$$
If $yz\neq 0$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
y^2\cdot yz=xz\cdot xu&\implies y=x^{2/3}\cdot u^{1/3}\\
z^2\cdot yz=yu\cdot xu&\implies z=x^{1/3}\cdot u^{2/3}.
\end{aligned}$$
In the case $yz=0$, then it is easy to see that $xu=0$ and $y=0=z$, where the above relations also hold.

Let $(a,b)=(x^{1/3},u^{1/3})$ and $$g:(a,b)\mapsto (a^3,a^2b,ab^2,b^3).$$
It is clear that $g$ is a homeomorphism.
And $$\partial g=\begin{pmatrix} 3a^2& 0\\ 2ab&a^2\\ b^2&2ab\\ 0&3b^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $g$ is an embedding when $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$.

It follows that $g(\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\})=f^{-1}(0)\setminus \{0\}$ is a embedded curve.